# What is the name of this component on a 600 W SMPS?

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, identification, components

I want to repair a Meanwell 600-12 power supply but I can't identify this component.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: (While showing the component with excellent detail, an image of a bigger part of the PCB might help - near input filter? Fusible resistor, maybe.) There is getting a PS to work again, and there is getting it to work reliably, as in for thousands of hours without further issue.

Comment: (There got to be quite a number of *different* `Meanwell 600-12` power supplies.)

Comment: Thank you so much yes, I will upload a picture of the pcb but this component follows NTC thermistor and 1 uF Film capacitor on AC line input

Comment: Which component from all of those seen in the pictures you mean? The pink resistor looking called R1, with M1/2WJ written on it? If you can't identify it, there are more letters if you take the part out. But from your description it is impossible to determine what it does in the circuit, is it in series to limit current, or in parallel to discharge residual charge in caps.

Comment: I mean the pink resistor written R1 on the pcb @Justme

Comment: When I removed it from the pcb for a closer look, it was written 680K and FU244 on different sides. When I used a fluke 179 digital multimeter to test resistance I got a reading of roughly 679 mega ohms. The smps that I took it out from was working I wanted to see this component for a similar power supply I have that is faulty in a sence that there is no output voltage and after I replaced every fried capacitor and resistor there was no output. Now I don't know whether it is the control IC which showed signs of corrosion on pin 1 and 2 or is it because I didn't put the same resistor

Comment: (took me a while to spot the fuse holder to the cutout-side of the light grey cuboid component. Have you removed the large yellow cuboid component between the chokes from *overall view* to *"For continued…"*? (Where in the overall view is the grey one?)

Comment: Yes @greybeard the large yellow film capacitors (cuboids) are replacement parts

Comment: Please consider moving some information from comments to the question body. Please check the resistance reading: Is it MOhms or kOhms? 680 kOhms would be a perfect discharge resistance for an X filter capacitor (about 470n), 2 W not to dissipate that much heat continuously, but for terminal distance and surge immunity.

Comment: It is M ohms on multimeter @greybeard

Comment: That's why I am confused because it is written 680K Ohms.... The Capacitor before it is 1 uF

Comment: (I guess I would try and check the 'meter with a "known good" 1MΩ.)

Comment: Alright, thank you.Do you have Whatsapp @greybeard?

Comment: Do you have a circuit diagram for 600watt 12Volt, 50 amp smps?

Comment: (I don't (both accounts). If I had, I'd strongly discourage to build one from scratch and that schematic.) What are you trying to achieve: Supply a load that's already there for least cost plausible?

Comment: Mmm I don't understand what you mean @greybeard